# Using Motion Analysis and Object Tracking in opencv for android for Pupil Movement

Tags: java, android, opencv, motion-detection, eye-tracking

I am constantly getting frames of an eye from a webcam. I need to detect where the pupil relative to its previous position using [Object Tracking](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) with OpenCv for Android.

So far I haven't been able to find any useful pointers as to how to go about it. Are there any links/tutorials that can help?

I have already used detection algorithms like Contour Detection, Hough Circles etc, which sometimes yield false positives so I wanted something more robust.

Comment: What your image looks like? Is it full screen eye or entire face image? Is it color or gray?

Comment: It is a fullscreen eye in color

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I can suggest you try implement ideas from paper:

Accurate Eye Center Location and Tracking Using Isophote Curvature

I have used this method, it gives good results, fast and simple.